# Unable to perform a Cross domain ajax call. - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis, iis-7, cross-domain

I have checked many post and tried every logic that were mentioned in various blogs and posts. But I am unable to perform a cross domain ajax call to an IIS server. Please anybody advice what else I should look into or configure it to get working. All your help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my ajax call:

```
var url = "http://mydomain .com/myauthorizeservice";                               
var jsonParam = JSON.stringify({ username: 'user007', password: 'pass007' });     
$.ajax({                                                                          
    type: "POST",                                                                 
    url: url,                                                                     
    crossDomain: true,                                                            
    data: jsonParam,                                                              
    success: fnSuccess,                                                           
    error: fnError,                                                               
    dataType: "json",                                                             
    contentType: "application/json"                                               
});                                                                               
function fnSuccess() {                                                            
    alert("Success");                                                             
}                                                                                 
function fnError() {                                                              
    alert("Error");                                                               
}
```

My config in the root web.config:-
[image]

Error:-
Access Denied.

Comment: what is the problem? any error messages?

Comment: Error:-  
Access Denied.

Comment: Does opening the url in a browser work?

Comment: Yes. Page is successfully loaded. Only the ajax call is not a success.

Comment: When I see it in fiddler I get- Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Can you use a dev tool like Chrome dev tools and give us the detailed headers in the request and response ?

Comment: @CamilleHodoul Thanks for your response. After lots of efforts I have made it working now. Check it out and let me know if I am still missing something that also should be kept in mind.

Comment: @wroniasty Thanks for your response. After lots of efforts I have made it working now. Check it out and let me know if I am still missing something that also should be kept in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really struggled a lot to make this thing work. Here some points that also matters and restrict the cross domain calls-
Note: I am using WCF REST service. and configurations are for IIS 7.5.

**1: Make sure your OPTIONSVerbHandler looks like-**

[image]

**2: Make sure you have the correct ordering in HandlerMappings-**

[image]

Rest settings and the way to perform ajax call is mentioned in the question.
Happy coding!